# How to tune babel loader to properly import a module named macro.js when using CRA

Tags: javascript, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-loader, vtk.js

I'm using a library vtk.js. VTK has a special design of classes (https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/docs/develop_class.html). When I write a class I need to import macro.js module which exposes several base methods such as getters/setters/newInstance etc (https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/blob/master/Sources/macro.js).

Looks like CRA uses some special loader for macro.js files. I get an error when trying to import such a file (`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`). If I copy an original file macro.js from @kitware/vtk.js to my local source folder I still get an error. Even if I remove all the contents of macro.js file I get an error (`The macro imported from "../macro" must be wrapped in "createMacro" which you can get from "babel-plugin-macros". Please refer to the documentation to see how to do this properly: https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/blob/master/other/docs/author.md#writing-a-macro`). However, when I rename macro.js to macro2.js the error is gone.

Is there some way how can I disable this macro loader?

Comment: You most likely want to use `craco` (https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) to override your CRA build settings.

Comment: Craco helps to customize webpack config of CRA, this I understand. But what exactly should be changed?

Comment: Does using `react-vtk-js` help?
https://github.com/Kitware/react-vtk-js
If it doesn't work, you can ask in their issue page, and might get a reply from the author. He seems very active.

Comment: I created an issue in vtk discource: https://discourse.vtk.org/t/how-to-tune-babel-loader-to-properly-import-a-module-named-macro-js-when-using-cra/5808